# As the domestic partner of a Marie Curie Fellow, what resource(s) should I consult?

Tags: marie-curie

Or to put this simply, what's a husband with his own skills to do while his wife is a fellow?  We're excited by my wife's well earned opportunity to travel and participate in the culture of another country[US to EU].  Through the participating institution, it sounds like we will have a family allowance but I'd love the opportunity to work/study/volunteer during the year or two that we're there.  I'd love to hear the stories of spouses/partners that have direct experience but I'd be very appreciative of pointers to information I should consult.  The fellowship website isn't really geared to partners, unsurprisingly.

Comment: You'll have to look at the visa rules for dependents in the specific country in question, or apply for e.g. a work visa of your own. I think [Schengen Visa info](https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/working-schengen-visa/) is a decent place to start, and maybe the [Expatriates stack exchange](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks, @anyon.  I understand why this question has been flagged as off-topic but I imagine future[and past] Marie Curie fellows with partners and dependents may come here looking for info not on the MCF website.